# opkg --force-downgrade - how does it work?

Tags: package, package-managers, opkg

I am trying to bring a package to an earlier version using opkg running this `--force-downgrade`  opkg command, but it seems it doesn't behave like it should. Did this option work for anybody so far? And if so, how shoud I use it?

It seems to me that once you installed the latest version of a package you are stuck with it and can't get to another version without removing the package and installing it again.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an earlier version of the ipk on the system and your are trying to call "opkg install  --force-downgrade"?